# Facebook Like button doesn't show up anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I implemented the like-button on the page http://www.racket-center.de on every subpage of this site. I noticed that it didn't show up on every page so I tried different implementation-versions (html5, iframe etc) but it didn't work. If I remember correctly the more I tried the less pages the button appeared on.

Now the button doesn't show up anymore – not even within the wizard at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ You can try it yourself: if you enter the URL of the site + then change another option to get the wizard checking the url the like-button will disappear.

I tried to debug via the linter and fixed some minor warnings it complained (e.g. adjusting the og:image-size to fit 200x200px) but that didn't bring back the button.

I guess the page is kind of blacklisted but I don't know + if it was blacklisted I don't know why.

Does anybody have a clue what might be going on here or kind point me to any resource about fb's blacklists?

Would be nice to get some help.

Thx,
Michael